# wild cards on find and ls

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to figure out the wild-cards to do file operations.

I have these files in a directory for testing purposes:

```
file_BSD.GIF  file_linux.gif  file_unix
```

See my ls command,

```
$ ls *{.GIF,.gif}
file_BSD.GIF  file_linux.gif
```

Which is OK.

But "find" doesn't seem to work the same way:

```
$ find -name *{.GIF,.gif}
find: paths must precede expression: file_linux.gif
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

By the way, I've read that "-iname" should locate both the uppercase and lowercase files, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
$find -iname *.gif

./file_linux.gif
```

(This should locate the .GIF file as well, right?).

Comment: To use `-iname` as you want, you must quote the pattern you give to it. I've added this as an answer.

Comment: As an aside, i think it's worth noting that braces (`{}`) in `-name` pattern are not recognized as being  special (See `-name pattern` in http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html). For example, you can't find jpgs and jpegs like this: `find -iname '*.jp{,e}g'`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`find -name *{.GIF,.gif}` is wrong.

This command is first expanded by the shell to `find -name *.GIF *.gif`

Then further expanded to :

```
find -name file_BSD.GIF  file_linux.gif 
# as you have only these files in directory
```

Now this `-name file_BSD.GIF  file_linux.gif` is passed to `find`. And this is **wrong** as there is no switch like `file_linux.gif` that is accepted by find.

What you need is this command.

```
find -name '*.GIF' -or -name '*.gif'
```

Assuming you want to collect `.gif` files in a case insensitive manner, this find command becomes,

```
find -iname '*.gif'
```

Note the single quotes (`'`) here. It means `*.GIF` should be sent to find *as is* without any shell expansion. And find will use this as pattern. This single quote is necessary unless you escape the shell meta-characters. In that case the command would look like

```
find -iname \*.gif
```

Comment: "Which is same as `find -iname '*.gif'`" No. This will happily accept a file ending with `.giF`, which the previous command does not accept.

Comment: In case you want to add actions, you'll have to add brackets: `find \( -name '*.GIF' -or -name '*.gif' \) -print`. Note that there are spaces around the brackets.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Technically you are correct. I have edited my answer to contain the assumption I took.

Answer (score 13):

You are having trouble with the parameter `-iname` of `find` because you must quote the patterns you give to it.

So, you should do:

```
find -iname '*.gif'
```

This is stated in the manual:

> "... Please note that you should quote patterns as a matter of course, otherwise the shell will expand any wildcard characters in them."

Answer (score 4):

You should understand that (in contrast to Windows) the shell is expanding the `*{.GIF,.gif}` before passing it to the `find` program.

You can feel what the shell does by replacing the program with `echo`.

So you should quote the program argument, like

```
   echo \-name '*{.GIF,.gif}'
```

so run

```
   find -name '*.{GIF,gif}'
```

Maybe you want

```
   find -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.GIF'
```

Please read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (and perhaps the [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page, to understand how the kernel run programs).